# why didnt appear console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

My question is related with react hooks. I'm doing api project for cars brand and model. As the first step when i selected from select element, thats will be install second select whats related with my first selected element. But i have a problem. when i select first step thats no appear console but when i second select console is appear my first select

```
function Home() {
  const [api, setApi] = useState({});
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const id = useDispatch((userId)=>modelAction(userId));


  let key;
  let history = useHistory();
   function handleClick(e){

   key = api.filter(item => item.var_title === e.target.value);


    setUserId({...key});

    console.log(userId);
    id({
      type: 'MODELS',
      id: userId
    })
   history.push('/model')

  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://api.carecusoft.com/tr/v1/chiptuning?key=testSA65D46ASD4AS8F4AS6F4A68')
    .then(res=> setApi(res.data))

    .catch(err => setErrors(true));
    console.log(api);

  },[userId]);



  return (
    <div>

      <select onChange={e=>handleClick(e)} as={Link} to='/model'>
        <option>Marka seç</option>
        {

          Object.values(api).map(item => {
            const {id, var_title} = item;
            return(
              <option key={id} value={var_title} >{var_title}</option>
            )
          })
        }
      </select> 


    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console log doesn't need to be in the useEffect.
Since it's not a side effect.

Have the console log outside above your return

Answer (score 0):

Because you log your data inside `handleClick` function where you **userid** set. You need to log your data in your `useEffect` to see changes.

> If you set your variables inside your **Render** with hooks in a
>   functional component changes in your variable appears with it's new value
>   in **useEffect** because you give the variable as a parameter to **useEffect**.

Like this example;

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log('userId', userId);
},[userId]);
```

means, **useEffect** only triggered when **userid** changes.

Try this and you can see clearly what i mean,

```
useEffect(()=>{
   axios.get('https://api.carecusoft.com/tr/v1/chiptuning?key=testSA65D46ASD4AS8F4AS6F4A68').then(res=> setApi(res.data))

   .catch(err => setErrors(true));
    console.log('api', api);
    console.log('userId', userId);
    id({
      type: 'MODELS',
      id: userId
    })
},[userId]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding,  your answer has been very useful